# TeamCity user defined environment variables

Tags: powershell, environment-variables, teamcity

I am trying to get user defined variables from TeamCity parameters which I set during runtime via PowerShell.

When I do `%variablename%` in PowerShell runner script window I get the value of the variable. However when I programmatically build a string with % sign it prints the literal. I have also tried using `$env:variablename` as per their documentation which does not help.

Below is the function I am writing to get the value of the env variable:

```
Function get-tc-env-var {

Param (
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[string]$env_var

  )
Process        
{

$var = Env:$env_var # tried both $Env and Env both dont work
                if (!$var)
                {

                Write-Host "Can't get environment variable:" $env_var

                }
                else { return $Var.trim()}
                    }
                     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get an environment variable by specifying its name through another variable you need to use `Get-Item`:

```
Function get-tc-env-var {

    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$env_var
    )
    Process        
    {
        $var = (Get-Item env:$env_var).value

        if (!$var)
        {
            Write-Host "Can't get environment variable:" $env_var
        }
        else
        { 
            return $Var.trim()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this works for one script but fails for the other script with the following error : any idea what could be wrong ?

Comment: What’s the error? Although you’re probably better posting a new question.